# Modifying Data before inserting it in Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb

I am doing an HTTP trigger in Azure Function which add or update data in the Cosmos Db based on a condition. The data which is inserted has a modified date key(see below). I would like to update this key into date when this trigger ran and updated the record in Cosmos Db. If the update of Modified Date key is not possible, then I would prefer adding a new key here like date Updated and insert the current date.

How can I achieve this??

here is the code and structure of data inserted

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,            
            ILogger log )
        {
           


            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            bool upsert = bool.Parse(req.Query["upsert"]);
            string cosmosDbKey = "TestDJIWEHLM+4Jw==";
            string cosmosDbInstance = "https://localhost:80761";
            string cosmosDbName = "TestProfiles";
            string cosmosDbCollection = "Profiles";
            Uri CollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( cosmosDbName, cosmosDbCollection );
            DocumentClient Client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( cosmosDbInstance ), cosmosDbKey );

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader( req.Body ).ReadToEndAsync();
           

            string responseMessage =  upsert;
               
            var rec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( requestBody );
            var obj = JObject.Parse( rec.ToString() );
            if( upsert )
            {
                await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(
                    CollectionUri,
                    obj );
            }
            else
            {
                await Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(
                CollectionUri,
                obj);
            }
          
            
            return new OkObjectResult( responseMessage );
           

        }
    }
```

The Obj which I am inserting/Update is of this format:

```
{
    "id": "Test",
    "Type": "tes",
    "LastModified": "2020-03-29T22:22:25.6016794Z",
    "Tags": `["ta` btest "," tabtest2 "]," Properties ":{}," Categories ":[]," Quality ":{" Level ":0}," System ":{" OSVersion ":{" Platform ":2," ServicePack ":" "," Version ":" 10.0.19042.0 "," VersionString ":" Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0 "}}," DataSets ":[{" Name ":" DataSet1 "," DataFiles ":[{" Name ":" Readme.txt "," LastModified ":" 2020 - 03 - 29T22: 21: 30.570373Z "," Digest ":{" Hash ":" sAxMlg == "," Length ":5}}]}]," FileStore ":{" Service ":" AZURE "}," _etag ":" \ "0500b9f2-0000-0c00-0000-5f884cba0000\"",
    "Trigger": true,
    "Project": "TDemo",
    "ProjectId": "0mh45lfb.zqr"
}
```

requestBody:

```
"{\"id\":\"Test\",\"DocType\":\"REC\",\"LastModified\":\"2020-03-29T22:22:25.6016794Z\",\"Tags\":[\"tabtest\",\"tabtest2\"],\"Properties\":{},\"Categories\":[],\"Quality\":{\"Level\":0},\"System\":{\"OSVersion\":{\"Platform\":2,\"ServicePack\":\"\",\"Version\":\"10.0.19042.0\",\"VersionString\":\"Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0\"}},\"DataSets\":[{\"Name\":\"DataSet1\",\"DataFiles\":[{\"Name\":\"Readme.txt\",\"LastModified\":\"2020-03-29T22:21:30.570373Z\",\"Digest\":{\"Hash\":\"sAnyGxMlg==\",\"Length\":5}}]}],\"FileStore\":{\"Service\":\"AZURE\"},\"_etag\":\"\\\"0500b9f2-0000-0c00-0000-5f884cba0000\\\"\",\"Trigger\":true,\"Project\":\"Test\",\"ProjectId\":\"0mh45lfb.zqr\"}"
```

Comment: Looking at your code as it stands, it appears you're deserializing to a `JObject` (`var rec = ...`) and then serializing that to a string (`rec.ToString()`) before deserializing it again (`var obj = JObject.Parse(...)`). Why not just do away with the fluff and write `var obj = JObject.Parse(requestBody);`?

Comment: As for your question, what have you tried so far in order to update the `LastModified` property?

Comment: if i do var obj= JObject.Parse(requestBody) i get this error "  Function1. Newtonsoft.Json: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '' on the line

Comment: What I tried was something like this f( obj.ContainsKey( "LastModified" ) )
            {
                obj["LastModified"] = DateTime.Now;
            }, this works fine, when the document is inserted first time but if I am updating, then it does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd get that error. I'd be interested to see the value of `requestBody` in that scenario. As for your actual issue, that seems correct for how you would at least modify the `JObject`, which suggests there's some kind of issue with using it to call `UpsertDocumentAsync`. Do any of the other fields get updated successfully in that scenario? Does it make a difference if you use `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: updated the question with request body and UTC.now does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by playing a little with **Newtonsoft.Json**:

```
 public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            bool upsert = bool.Parse(req.Query["upsert"]);
            string cosmosDbKey = "TestDJIWEHLM+4Jw==";
            string cosmosDbInstance = "https://localhost:80761";
            string cosmosDbName = "TestProfiles";
            string cosmosDbCollection = "Profiles";
            Uri CollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(cosmosDbName, cosmosDbCollection);
            DocumentClient Client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(cosmosDbInstance), cosmosDbKey);

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();


            string responseMessage = upsert;

            var rec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBObject>(requestBody);
            rec.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var obj = JObject.Parse(rec.ToString());

            if (upsert)
            {
                await Client.CreateDocumentAsync(
                    CollectionUri,
                    obj);
            }
            else
            {
                await Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(
                CollectionUri,
                obj);
            }


            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);


        }

        public class DBObject
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
            public string[] Tags { get; set; }
            public string Project { get; set; }
            public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

*Suggestion (not a part of your question's answer):* Don't take `LastModified` value in request body of Azure Function. You should always change `DateTime` (CDC - Change Data Capture) values at Data Access layer.

Comment: thanks, and what if I have to insert LastModified key if that key is not present? Can you elaborate more on the suggesstion on CDC part.

Comment: If you have to insert LastModified Key, 1. If Key is not present in Request payload, the above code will work. 2. If Key is not present in CosmosDB, the same code shall work. Further, you don't have exact CDC, but a very small part of it. So, whenever you add CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, etc. they should be assigned values just before saving to DB to have accurate time (excluding http call time, other operations time, etc.). I recommend you to read about CDC here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd266396(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: so you are saying if I have to insert a new key, lets name it as LastUpdatedClientDate then above code will work if the key is not present in Request body?

Comment: Yes, because `var rec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBObject>(requestBody);` line of code will put value of `LastUpdatedClientDate` as `DateTime.MinValue` (default).